# How to wrap 2 components in a div from the template content.xml file?

Tags: aem

I have two components that should be configured in a cq template, in the content.xml file (in the jcr:content node).
I don't have a page component for my template, so I cannot do something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper_div">
   <cq:include resourceType="/my/first/component"/>
   <cq:include resourceType="/my/second/component"/>
</div>
```

Is there a way to define a div container from within content.xml?

Comment: If you dont have page component for template, then how you will render the content over the pages. There must be resourceType for that template.

Comment: Only the superResourceType is set for the template and I don't want to modify the page component corresponding to the superResourceType, because this is something specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be one trick, you can add below to your content.xml file of your template.

```
  <jcr:content
        jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
        sling:resourceType="path/of/page/page-component">
        <par
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys">
            <simple
                jcr:lastModified="{Date}2015-05-05T12:16:19.895+05:30"
                jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="path/components/content/component1"/>
            <simple1
                jcr:lastModified="{Date}2015-05-05T12:16:19.895+05:30"
                jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="path/components/content/component2"/>
        </par>
    </jcr:content>
</jcr:root>
```

This will create the content nodes for the page using this template, but to make this work you must have parsys included in your rendering page component `path/of/page/page-component` e.g. `<cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />`

Also there are some other ways like to add node of cq:template under your page component to pre populate the components.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Ok...but where is the wrapper div? The code that you posted is exactly what I used, but I also want to have the 2 components inside a wrapper div on which I can set some css class.

Comment: You can look over page source that what is the wrapper div for these components. Here parsys is the wrapper component. Also you can try <cq:include path="par-wrapper" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />. Also you may need to change the name of <par to <par-wrapper in context.xml. and apply css classes over par-wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case I will have an additional parsys even if it's not necessary...

Comment: Finally we have solved our problem via css, but VDhim answer was also a possible solution.